# Hough accumulator and the local maximum

Tags: opencv

After reading the hough.cpp I don't understand the line:

```
r += (numrho - 1) / 2;
```

We find the rho :with the equation `int r = cvRound( j * tabCos[n] + i * tabSin[n] );` Why to add `r+=r += (numrho - 1) / 2;`  ?

If someone could explaine precisely the local maximum find operation that would be really nice.

the hough code can be found here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp

Answer (score 0):

I don't program in CPP but I believe the cvRound object has made use of math operators, to change certain aspect of the cvRound object by using mathematical operations. Here is some info on cvRound object.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

And here is some info on the addition operator in CPP.

http://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/operator-overloading

By looking at theses sources I hope you find what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In the parameter space(r, theta), we have

r = x cos(theta) + y sin(theta)

The key point is that **r could be negtive**!

So you should shift r to non-negtive by adding  (numrho - 1) / 2

Hope it helps.